# Android open browser instead of drive app

Tags: android, html, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to get this to open into my google drive app.
But the first time i reset my browser it asks me if i want to open this link then it opens into the app. next time i open the link it just opens in my mobile browser.
have tried different versions of the link suggested in here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113680/how-to-open-google-drive-links-directly-in-google-drive-app

docs.google.com/file/d/*link*/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.